# wordpress: Redirect homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cookies

The homepage of my Wordpress site is set to display my latest posts.

I also created a landing page which includes a form for users to fill out for a free consultation.

How can I make it so that when first-time users go to the homepage, they will be redirected to the landing page?  (But clicking on my site logo should still take them back to my regular homepage showing my latest posts.)

After users have filled out the "get a free consultation" form on my landing page, we would create a cookie or something so that whenever they next visit the homepage, they will just see the regular homepage with latest posts - not see the landing page any more.

Is there a way to write a code for this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

[setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) is probably a good option.

```
if(!$_COOKIE["been_here_before"]) {
  setcookie("been_here_before", true); 
  header('Location: /consultation'); // Your free consultation page
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Where does this code go? I tried putting it in header.php but it gave me an error

Comment: What kind of error? You would probably be best modifying this to execute once the form has submitted as well to ensure the users fill in the form before the cookie is written.

Comment: Bad solution, setting cookies that won't expire is just bad

Comment: The intention wasn't really to set indefinitely expired cookies. It is used as an example coupled with the documentation on how to use

Answer (score 0):

The way to achive this is a little bit more complicated.
The best practice for this is to have your form in an overlay on the homepage, the user sees the form when accessing your website but has an option to close that layer (exemple:"already fiiled the form..."). After the user submits the form or clicks "close" then set a session variable that will be used so the user won't receive the overlay again in that session. An website that does that is [this one](http://www.groupon.ro/) which asks the user to register for the newsletter. If the user is already register then he can click "Already registerd?" (=Sunteti deja înregistrat?) and the overlay disapears for that session.
If the form submision is mandatory for all users to get access to the website, then force them to login in the landing page. [Here](http://www.plumdistrict.com/) is an example for that.